# Invoke nested deepobject method via reflection

Tags: java, kotlin, reflection

Is it possible to invoke nested method inside nested object from real object using reflection?
Something like this

```
val fieldDefinition = chatClient.javaClass.getDeclaredField("class1")
  .type.getDeclaredField("class2").type.getDeclaredField("class3")
```

Real object i have is chatClient and i want to invoke method of class3, which i cannot obtain directly but via class1 path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a logic of fetching nested fields in a function inside a `for` loop , so that you can avoid code duplication.

Whole code example in java:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

class Class1 {
    Class2 class2 = new Class2();

}
class Class2 {
    Class3 class3 = new Class3();
}
class Class3 {
    Class4 class4 = new Class4();
}
class Class4 {

    public void display(){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }

}


public class Test {

    static Object getFieldValue(String fieldPath ,Object object) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        String[] pathList = fieldPath.split("\\.");
        for(String path : pathList){
            Field field = object.getClass().getDeclaredField(path);
            field.setAccessible(true);
            object = field.get(object);
        }
        return object;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException {
        Class1 class1Object = new Class1();
        Object object = getFieldValue("class2.class3.class4", class1Object);

        Method method = object.getClass().getMethod("display");
        method.invoke(object);

    }
}
```

Here `fieldPath` in `getFieldValue` means path of the nested field object.

Comment: Thanks! Is it also possible to get the variable name and set it via reflection?

Comment: @Ritesh Did you encountered any problem calling the setter?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to obtain objects as you go.

```kotlin
val class1 = chatClient.javaClass.kotlin.memberProperties.first { it.name == "class1" }.get(chatClient)!!
val class2 = class1.javaClass.kotlin.memberProperties.first { it.name == "class2" }.get(class1)!!
val class3 = class2.javaClass.kotlin.memberProperties.first { it.name == "class3" }.get(class2)!!
(class3 as ObjectType).method()
```

You cannot do this by accessing fields using java reflection due to the fact, the fields are `private`. Either you can use java reflection and access auto-generated getters `getClass1`, `getClass2`, etc. or use k-reflect.

Example using java reflection:

```kotlin
val class1 = chatClient.javaClass.getMethod("getClass1").invoke(chatClient)
val class2 = class1.javaClass.getMethod("getClass2").invoke(class1)
val class3 = class2.javaClass.getMethod("getClass3").invoke(class2)

(class3 as ObjectType).method()
```

Comment: Thanks Animesh. I tried the below solution and it works. Is there a better solution you can think of.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it works, is there a better solution?

```
   val fieldDefinition1 = chatClient.javaClass.getDeclaredField("class1")
    fieldDefinition1.isAccessible = true
    val fieldValue1 = fieldDefinition1.get(chatClient)

    val fieldDefinition2 = fieldDefinition1.type.getDeclaredField("class2")
    fieldDefinition2.isAccessible = true
    val fieldValue2 = fieldDefinition2.get(fieldValue1)


    val fieldDefinition3 =  fieldDefinition2.type.getDeclaredField("class3")
    fieldDefinition3.isAccessible = true
    val fieldValue3 = fieldDefinition3.get(fieldValue2)

    val myMethod = fieldValue3.javaClass.getDeclaredMethod("methodName")
    myMethod.isAccessible  = true
    myMethod.invoke(fieldValue3)
```